# How to group by week Cloudera impala

Tags: cloudera, impala

How to group Impala query result by week? The data looks like:

```
    userguid                 eventtime
0   66AB1405446C74F2992016E5 2014-08-01T16:43:05Z
1   66AB1405446C74F2992016E5 2014-08-02T20:12:12Z
2   4097483F53AB3C170A490D44 2014-08-03T18:08:50Z
3   4097483F53AB3C170A490D44 2014-08-04T18:10:08Z
4   4097483F53AB3C170A490D44 2014-08-05T18:14:51Z
5   4097483F53AB3C170A490D44 2014-08-06T18:15:29Z
6   4097483F53AB3C170A490D44 2014-08-07T18:17:15Z
7   4097483F53AB3C170A490D44 2014-08-08T18:18:09Z
8   4097483F53AB3C170A490D44 2014-08-09T18:18:18Z
9   4097483F53AB3C170A490D44 2014-08-10T18:23:30Z
```

The expected result is:

```
date                    count of different userguid
2014-08-01~2014-08-07   40
2014-08-08~2014-08-15   20
2014-08-16~2014-08-23   10
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If `eventtime` is stored as a `timestamp`:

```
SELECT TRUNC(eventtime, "D"), COUNT(DISTINCT userguid)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY TRUNC(eventtime, "D")
ORDER BY TRUNC(eventtime, "D");
```

Else if `eventtime` is stored as a `string`:

```
SELECT TRUNC(CAST(eventtime AS TIMESTAMP), "D"), COUNT(DISTINCT userguid)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY TRUNC(CAST(eventtime AS TIMESTAMP), "D")
ORDER BY TRUNC(CAST(eventtime AS TIMESTAMP), "D");
```

For more information on the `TRUNC` function, see the [Cloudera Impala documentation on Date and Time Functions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_datetime_functions.html).

Comment: Can you explain the answer ? How to do this for grouping from Sunday to Saturday of next week?

Answer (score 0):

In Impala, TRUNC(timestamp, "D") means finding the starting day of the week. You can have a look at the Impala Date and Time functions [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html).

For example:

```
select trunc(cast('2016-11-10' as timestamp), "D")
+---------------------------------------------+
| trunc(cast('2016-11-10' as timestamp), 'd') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2016-11-07 00:00:00                         |
+---------------------------------------------+

+---------------------------------------------+
| trunc(cast('2016-11-09' as timestamp), 'd') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2016-11-07 00:00:00                         |
+---------------------------------------------+

+---------------------------------------------+
| trunc(cast('2016-11-11' as timestamp), 'd') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2016-11-07 00:00:00                         |
+---------------------------------------------+
```